# Identify if ion-input value has been cleared

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a way to identify if `ion-input` content has been cleared, I would like to execute some code after this condition has happened.

I have an input as follows:

```
<ion-input clearInput value="clear me" [(ngModel)]="myValue"></ion-input>
```

`clearInput` indicates `ion-input` to show a clear icon in the input when there is a value. Clicking it clears the input.

What I have been doing so far is checking on changes and execute a function when the value gets cleared, which might not be the case when the user just cleared the input with `backspace` or `delete`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a setter/getter. Something like:

```
private _myValue: string;
 set myValue(value: string) {
   if(value === '') {
     //logic for when value is empty
   }
   this._myValue = value;
 }

 get myValue() {
   return this._myValue;
 }
```